# How to make mysql queries with where condition run faster on large tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the 2 queries below on a mysql dB table which has about 10 million rows. The first count one is quite fast. The second is quite slow (maybe 10 times slower).

```
SELECT count(*) as count
from $table
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, '>', 3) LIKE '%$mylocation%'
... show count


SELECT name, location, hotel, rating     
FROM $table
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, '>', 3) LIKE '%$mylocation%'    
...loop to show results
```

location column has values like - Spain>Canary Islands>Lanzarote>Some Resort

Index set on 'location' column - Table is MyISAM

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can speed up the second query. I understand they both work a bit differently.

Comment: What sort of content do you have in location which means you have to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`?

Comment: The index is irrelevant. A function cannot use an index :-( (Although, starting with MySQL 8.0.13, it is possible to create a 'functional index'!)

Comment: Sorry i added the content type to the question its like - Spain>Canary Islands>Lanzarote>Some Resort

Comment: I thought I needed to index the column thats in the where clause

Comment: Instead consider whether there is scope to normalise your data - or, perhaps use a JSON data type (not something I know much about)

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE $table;  and B) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  (each query); and C) complete query submitted for your two timings for six results to be posted for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Tip:
To avoid using something like `SELECT count(*) as count` Which takes a lot of resource from your server.
Recommendation:
Store the values into a Database column, everytime you insert something into your database

```
from $table
```

Store them in another database table and call it "Sums" , everything something is inserted into `$table`, Update the value of "Sums" Table to a higher number.